# Alternative to QUERY nested in COUNTIF for column array in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, countif, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Currently I have a formula which is working very well, however, it is making my sheets extremely slow as I am using more than one of these `COUNTIF` queries.

```
 =IF($O$1="YT",COUNTIFS(
 QUERY(Contacts!$Q$3:$EZ, "select V,AC,AJ,AQ,AX,BE,BL,BS, BZ ,CG,CN,CU,DB,DI,DP,DW,ED,EK,ER,EY", 0), $T22,       
 QUERY(Contacts!$Q$3:$EZ, "select U,AB,AI,AP,AW,BD,BK,BR,`BY`,CF,CM,CT,DA,DH,DO,DV,EC,EJ,EQ,EX", 0), U$21),    
 COUNTIFS(
 QUERY(Contacts!$Q$3:$EZ, "select T,AA,AH,AO,AV,BC,BJ,BQ, BX ,CE,CL,CS,CZ,DG,DN,DU,EB,EI,EP,EW", 0), $O$1,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 QUERY(Contacts!$Q$3:$EZ, "select V,AC,AJ,AQ,AX,BE,BL,BS, BZ ,CG,CN,CU,DB,DI,DP,DW,ED,EK,ER,EY", 0), $T22,      
 QUERY(Contacts!$Q$3:$EZ, "select U,AB,AI,AP,AW,BD,BK,BR,`BY`,CF,CM,CT,DA,DH,DO,DV,EC,EJ,EQ,EX", 0), U$21))
```

Basically what this does is search the month from a drop-down in the dashboard, and then counts the number of calls by filtering Call Category, Sales Person and Month. The reason I have 2 `COUNTIF`'s is that the first calculates based on the whole year hence `YT = "Year Total"`

The calls come from an array of columns, hence the query for different columns.
Any feedback would be much appreciated.

I'm more proficient with functions than I am with app script, but always willing to learn, so if there is an app script solution I would be more than grateful to learn.

I look forward to learning from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to kill all your query formulas (all those which looks like the example in your question) and replace them with this build:

```
=IF($G$2="Year Total",
 COUNTA(FILTER(Contacts!V3:V,  Contacts!V3:V=$B12,  Contacts!U3:U=E$11))+
 COUNTA(FILTER(Contacts!AC3:AC,Contacts!AC3:AC=$B12,Contacts!AB3:AB=E$11))+
 etc...


,COUNTA(FILTER(Contacts!T3:T,  Contacts!T3:T=$G$2,  Contacts!V3:V=$B12,  Contacts!U3:U=E$11))+
 COUNTA(FILTER(Contacts!AA3:AA,Contacts!AA3:AA=$G$2,Contacts!AC3:AC=$B12,Contacts!AB3:AB=E$11))+
 etc...

 )
```

[image: 0]

this will give you ~80% boost

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your data or at least post a screenshot showing an idea how they look like? That always helps in understanding what you want to do.

Anyway, the first thing I'd do would be to replace your `QUERY()` calls with straight `{}` addressing, that alone should speed things up. See if this helps:

```
 =IF($O$1="YT",
    COUNTIFS(
      {V,AC,AJ,AQ,AX,BE,BL,BS,BZ,CG,CN,CU,DB,DI,DP,DW,ED,EK,ER,EY}, $T22,
      {U,AB,AI,AP,AW,BD,BK,BR,BY,CF,CM,CT,DA,DH,DO,DV,EC,EJ,EQ,EX}, U$21),    
    COUNTIFS(
      {T,AA,AH,AO,AV,BC,BJ,BQ,BX,CE,CL,CS,CZ,DG,DN,DU,EB,EI,EP,EW}, $O$1,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      {V,AC,AJ,AQ,AX,BE,BL,BS,BZ,CG,CN,CU,DB,DI,DP,DW,ED,EK,ER,EY}, $T22,      
      {U,AB,AI,AP,AW,BD,BK,BR,BY,CF,CM,CT,DA,DH,DO,DV,EC,EJ,EQ,EX}, U$21))
```

Another simple speedup possible would be to delete any rows below the last row for which you have data.

Comment: I would place straight curly brackets, but the information I am looking for sits in another sheet within the same workbook, hence why I queried "Contacts!$Q$3:$EZ"

The sheet example can be found at this link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LflHtO6SjotBC-9GUY2P8ZSZXEDM4y2dn79zbsGLKPI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I realised I didnt open it to public, only company. It's open now.

Comment: You can use the curly braces addressing on the other sheet too, e.g. in place of "V" use "Contacts!V3:V". As things stand, you have 5 x 5 x 6 = 150 QUERY() calls, each processing a 20x2000 rows range -- no wonder things are a little slow. Try the proposed addressing.